# cloth keeps pulsing when simulating on rigged character

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm new to cloth Physics in blender and I'm trying to simulate cloth on a cape rigged to my character. It wont stop blowing or pulsing even when the character stops moving in the animation. I've tried several things that solved similar problems in other questions to no avail. For example, I increased the poly count, collision settings and weight and it still pulses. The mesh isn't going inside one of the collision meshes either

Here's a little gif showing the issue
[image]

Just let me know if you need the model and I'll share the link